# Adaptec 6805 accessing to JBOD with GPT / NTFS

Tags: hardware-raid, ntfs, gpt, adaptec

I have several hard drives with GPT and NTFS volumes, and I plugged them to an Adaptec 6805 but The volumes are not visibles from Windows 10 and from MaxView. The only option I have ti to initialize (metadata and drive), which if I understand well will erease everything, which is something I do not want.

How can I access to the NTFS volumes from the 6805 in this context ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without losing data and writing new metadata on drives by the 6805, according to Adaptec/Microchip.

Only an HBA adapter such as the Broadcom 9500 serie can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 6805 is in JBOD mode.  It sounds like it might be in RAID mode, and since it doesn't find any RAID headers on the disk it wants you to initialize the disks to create a RAID.

Comment: I tried to add JBOD disks from the controller BIOS, but the controller refused since disks are not "initialized" (but they are formatted as GPT with NTFS).  But indeed there is no initialized disk and subsequently the "BIOS is not installed" at bootup.

Comment: Sorry, comments limit the formatting options.  In "Manage JBODs" from the main logical device configuration menu, do you see the drives there?  In the [manual](http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/user_guides/microsemi_raid_controller_iug_6_2017.pdf) I am seeing this.  I would HIGHLY recommend testing before attempting on drives with important data.

Converting a JBOD Into a Simple Volume
You can convert any JBOD into a simple volume.  
1. Select Manage JBODs from the main Logical Device Configuration menu.  
2. Select the JBOD that you want to morph into a simple volume and press Ctrl+V.